# How to change data in firebase and check id auto increment

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Hye, my problem is to rewrite if the user put the same nameItem that will change the price and the quantityItem, if not the item will add new id. i also do auto increment on id.

My Database :
[image]

This is how i try but when the name == nameItem can't read and run on else in on DataChange.

```
if(i != 0){
        for(id1 = 1; id1<=i; id1++){
            if(id1 != 0){

                final DatabaseReference reff1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CartList").child(userID).child(String.valueOf(id1));

                reff1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String carinama = dataSnapshot.child("nameItem").getValue().toString();
                        String changequantity = dataSnapshot.child("quantityItem").getValue().toString();

                        if(nameItem == carinama) {

                            int calcQuantity = Integer.parseInt(cdtb.getQuantityItem());
                            newpositionItem = newpositionItem + calcQuantity;
                            String x = String.valueOf(newpositionItem);
                            cdtb.setQuantityItem(x);
                            int price1Item = Integer.parseInt(priceItem);
                            newpositionItem = newpositionItem * price1Item;
                            cdtb.setPriceItem(d2f.format(newpositionItem));
                            reff1.setValue(cdtb);
                            id1 = i;
                        }else {
                            int calcQuantity = Integer.parseInt(changequantity);
                            newpositionItem = newpositionItem + calcQuantity;
                            String x = String.valueOf(newpositionItem);
                            cdtb.setQuantityItem(x);
                            double price1Item = Double.parseDouble(priceItem);
                            newpositionItem = newpositionItem * price1Item;
                            cdtb.setPriceItem(d2f.format(newpositionItem));
                            reff1.setValue(cdtb);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }else {

            }
        }
    }else{
        cdtb.setImageItem(imageUrl);
        cdtb.setNameItem(nameItem);
        cdtb.setPriceItem(d2f.format(calcPrice));
        cdtb.setSpecification(specItem);
        cdtb.setQuantityItem(positionItem);
        reff.child(String.valueOf(++maxid)).setValue(cdtb);
    }
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nameItem  and carinama is **String**

in java to compare two string you must use **equals** method **not "=="**

because == will compare object location in memory and not the content string

so you code condition will be

```
if(nameItem.equals(carinama)){
           //your code here 
 }
```

Comment: @afiq your welcome, please mark my answer as correct if solve the problem